# Designing A reader and Processor using Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a Core java module, where in there, there are events which are read and then those read events are needed to be organized into some form

I have figured the OOPS deign something like this

EventManager has Two Objects, EventReader and EventScheduler

The EventReader reads the data from the text input file and gives back an array of Objects of type Event.

The EventScheduler takes in as input the Event array object and processes them (including sorting the array as per its convince, then arrange them as using (KnapSackProblem) according to some criteria).

Inside the EventScheduler, I have kept methods which sorts and then arranges the Events as per the desired output.

So Is this design High Cohesion and Loose Coupling.. Threotically atleast.. Since I cannot share the entire diagram on the site.

I need a good design and wanted to know what is the correct design for this scenario.

Kindly let me know if you need more design information in this regards to understand the scenario more.

Just a note, I am actually not aiming at improving the performance, but only a very clean design concept for such a scenario.

Any Help is most welcome!

Thanks in Advance :)
Cheers

Comment: for some reason this sounds like Spring Batch

Comment: well, actually I am just trying to figure out a very clean design for such a scenario, any links or references highlighting the design aspects for such a scenario will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

This is just another sample of solving Producer/Consumer problem of Distributed Programming.

I was thinking if we can solve your event reading and processing sequentially but then I realize that your text input may change while time flows. That means you need to read new inputs also.

Here you need to figure out EventReader and EventScheduler are different processors. Reader needs to read and prepare event. Scheduler needs to get event and schedule it for processing. And yes should be loosely coupled.

Comment: It can be thought of like a Producer Consumer Problem, but here the sequence is limited and then the processing is done on that finite set of data only, its just that the designing needs to be perfect with single responsibility of objects and stuff. Any good links for solving this case scenarios is most welcomed.

Comment: You can use message bus, or just sequential programming without using threads, after finishing its work, reader can just invoke scheduler.

Comment: Actually that can increase the performance,but right now I am just focusing on the design patterns like single responsibility and stuff and how that can done better, eg: I have done a initial design of creating domain objects, kindly refer the above line in my question "EventManager has Two Objects, EventReader and EventScheduler". I am still at the designing phase of this module, hence , any help in designing stating specific design patter will be most helpfull to solve such common  problems